# localStorage onClick toggleClass

Tags: jquery

I want the following operation to be saved as local storage after clicking, but I do not get any results

```
burger.on('click', function () {
 page.toggleClass('toggle');
 sidebar.toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Because i don't see any code for save data into localStorage

Comment: you need to add more information(context) in your question. What data do you want to save in the local storage? Is a page status, a sidebar status?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what you want to store in localstorage? here you missed adding data into localstorage code.

If you want to store something in localstorage you can do that something like...

**To Add**

```
localStorage.setItem("mytime", Date.now());
```

**To Get**

```
var x = localStorage.getItem("mytime");
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you want to use localStorage to keep a layout state for page and sidebar:

```
// Set a default object for your layout state
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  page: false,
  sidebar: false
};

// Create a namespace for your object that will be set into localStorage
const NAMESPACE = 'YOUR_APP_NAME';

// Call once to init your workspace default values
const init = function() {
  localStorage.setItem(NAMESPACE, JSON.stringify(DEFAULT_STATE));
}

// Generic function to get the whole state object or just a specific item from it
const getState = function(specificItem) {
  const state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(NAMESPACE));
  return state[specificItem] || state;
}

// Generic function to change state
const changeState = function(itemToChange, newState) {
  if (!itemToChange && !newState) {
    // If no props are given, quit this function
    return;
  }
  
  if (itemToChange && !newState) {
    // If only a single parameter is given, rewrite the entire state with what is given
    localStorage.setItem(NAMESPACE, itemToChange);
    return;
  }
  
  if (itemToChange && newState) {
    // If both parameters are given, rewrite the specific, provided key
    let currentValue = getState();
    currentValue[itemToChange] = newState;
    localStorage.setItem(NAMESPACE, currentValue);
  }
}

init();

burger.on('click', function () {
  const CURRENT_STATE = getState();

  // Update the current state variable
  CURRENT_STATE.page = !CURRENT_STATE.page;
  CURRENT_STATE.sidebar = !CURRENT_STATE.sidebar;

  // Supposing that your "page" and "sidebar" are referencing a DOM element
  CURRENT_STATE.page ? page.classList.add('toggle') : page.classList.remove('toggle');
  CURRENT_STATE.sidebar ? sidebar.classList.add('active') : sidebar.classList.remove('active');
  
  
  // Write the new state into localStorage
  setState(CURRENT_STATE);
});
```